# Error installing node.js on bluehost

Tags: python, node.js, bluehost

My attempt to install node.js on bluehost is failing. The last error I get is about having a read only file system. I set the directory I'm installing from/to to 755.

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home7/arielbal/node-v0.12.0/out'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home7/arielbal/node-v0.12.0/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
/ramdisk/bin/python tools/install.py install '' '/usr/local'
installing /usr/local/bin/node
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home7/arielbal/node-v0.12.0/out'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home7/arielbal/node-v0.12.0/out'
ln -fs out/Release/node node
/ramdisk/bin/python tools/install.py install '' '/usr/local'
installing /usr/local/bin/node
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/install.py", line 202, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[:])
  File "tools/install.py", line 197, in run
    if cmd == 'install': return files(install)
  File "tools/install.py", line 130, in files
    action(['out/Release/node'], 'bin/node')
  File "tools/install.py", line 79, in install
    def install(paths, dst): map(lambda path: try_copy(path, dst), paths)
  File "tools/install.py", line 79, in <lambda>
    def install(paths, dst): map(lambda path: try_copy(path, dst), paths)
  File "tools/install.py", line 70, in try_copy
    try_unlink(target_path) # prevent ETXTBSY errors
  File "tools/install.py", line 33, in try_unlink
    os.unlink(path)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/bin/node'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: Is it shared hosting? and also, did you check the permissions on the dir to make sure they went through once you changed them?

Comment: It is shared hosting. I should have checked the permissions.

Comment: I just realized that it's trying to install into /usr/locl/bin, which I definitely don't have write access to. I guess I need to figure out a way to install it as some sort of a local install.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. After downloading, I ran configure with the --prefix option. With your homedir as the example:

```
./configure --prefix="/home7/arielbal/node"
```

then built and installed it (make && make install). That installs everything locally under your 'node' folder.

After that, set your path to include the node binary:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/home7/arielbal/node/bin"
```

Hope that helps!